# How to stop Outlook from saving an email in Sent folder when I respond to a calendar event?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, user-experience

When I respond to an Outlook calendar event by choosing one of the Accept/Tentative/Decline options, the response get sent as an email and it clutters my Sent email folder.  Is there a way to suppress this email?

Answer (score 0):

You could set an Outlook Inbox rule, the message sender is you, add 'Accepted','Tentative' Declined' three words to the subject. Move the message to the other folder.
[image]